# Set theory venn diagram help. Homework

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am new to set theory and one of our exercises is the following question:
decide on the truth or falsity of the claim that, for all sets A, B, C, D
[A ∩ B ⊆ C ∩ D] ⇒ [(A∆B) ⊇ (C∆D)].

I have drawn the following Venn diagrams[image]

And thus, from this visual proof, I conclude that the claim is false. If someone could validate my answer that would be appreciated, but even better if someone could tell me how I could prove this using set notation that would be even better or just put me in the direction of some helpful websites.

Anyway all feedback is appreciated.

Comment: You shouldn't prove them by diagrams. A proof always is based on definitions. Your van diagrams are just one arrangements for the sets while your question say **for all**.

Comment: I don't think, you can write like this.

Comment: I don't see how these sets can be represented in any other way, LuckyGuy?

Comment: @seriallchiller There are many other ways to draw the diagrams.  Even the part on the left (and I think the part on the right is flawed... see my answer) could be drawn differently.  Since the only requirement is $A \cap B \subseteq C \cap D$, you don't need to have the entire sets $A$ and $B$ in the intersection of $C$ and $D$ as you have drawn.  You could have $A$ and $B$ doing lots of different things as long as the intersection is contained in $C \cap D$.

Comment: @seriallchiller And that's sort of the point of why you can't prove things by diagram.  There's no guarantee that you've been clever enough to draw every possible diagram.  Of course, you can prove things are false by diagram, but usually using a diagram for intuition and then writing down an actual counterexample is the advisable way to go.

Comment: @Rori Thanks for clearing that up, I see what the other two comments were trying to say to me :)

Comment: @seriallchiller No problem.  Let me know if my answer makes sense to you.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that the claim is false.  Once you've decided that the claim is false, the best thing to do is find a counterexample.  To show the statement is false, all you have to do is find some way of defining sets A,B,C,D so that the claim fails.  One possible way of doing this (there may be simpler ones) is to say,

Let
$$ A = \{ 1 \}, \quad B = \{ 1 \}, \quad C = \{ 1, 2 \}, \quad D = \{ 1, 3\}. $$
From here we compute to see the left side is true,
$$ A \cap B = \{ 1 \}, \qquad C \cap D = \{ 1 \}$$
Thus indeed,
$$ A \cap B \subseteq C \cap D.$$
For the expression on the right,
$$ A \Delta B = (A \smallsetminus B) \cup (B \smallsetminus A) = \varnothing$$
And,
$$ C \Delta D = (C \smallsetminus D) \cup (D \smallsetminus C) = \{ 2,3 \}.$$
But
$$ \varnothing \nsupseteq \{ 2,3 \}$$
Hence, the expression is on the right is false.  Therefore, the statement as a whole is false.

**A word on your diagram**

The diagram you have drawn does not accurately represent the statement.  Once you have defined the sets $A,B,C,D$ on the left, you cannot change them in the diagram on the right.  So, the labels you have on the right don't make sense to me.  Do you mean to label things on the right $A \Delta B$ and $C \Delta D$?  You can't just label a different section with $A$, etc.

Comment: is the right hand side not a representation of (A∆B) ⊇ (C∆D)?

Comment: @seriallchiller I don't think so.  You have labels $A,B,C,D$ on the right which are different from $A,B,C,D$ on the left.  The sets $A,B,C,D$ must stay the same.  So on the right you need to label what is $A \Delta B$ and $C \Delta D$.  You can't just put $A,B,C,D$ on different things because that would mean the sets themselves have changed.

Comment: @seriallchiller What I'm trying to say is $A,B,C,D$ are fixed sets, so should be the same thing on both sides.  What you want to label is what is $A \cap B$, what is $C \cap D$, and what is $A \Delta B$, $C \Delta D$.  The things which are $A,B,C,D$ can't change.